# How can I get get index and distance in Nearest functions in Low Version

Tags: compatibility, nearest

```
Nearest[{"I'm", "sorry", "Dave"} -> All, "David"]

{<|"Element" -> "Dave", "Index" -> 3, "Distance" -> 2|>}
```

However, in a WolframScript.wl file, it gives:
Maybe in a low Mathematica Version 11.0
    Nearest[{"I'm", "sorry", "Dave"} -> All, "David"]

```
{3}
```

How can I get the both `Index` and 'Distance' in an `nf` function in WolframScript in low version of Mathematica.

```
nf=Nearest[data]

nf[example]={index, distance}
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions (see tag descriptions). Can you tag this question more appropriately?

Comment: Mathematica 8.0.4 gives {3}.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. It is likely that you are using a WolframScript executable from a different version than 11.1. This feature of `Nearest` was introduced only in 11.1.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default distance function for strings is [`EditDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EditDistance.html) you could code it manually with something like:

```
stringNF[a : {__String}] := 
  With[{fn = Nearest[a -> All]}, 
    Function[b, {#, EditDistance[b, Extract[a, #]]} & @ fn[b]]
  ]

nf = stringNF[{"I'm", "sorry", "Dave"}];

nf["David"]
```

> ```
> {{3}, 2}
> ```